# How to avoid custom error.apx redirect screen for Sharepoint custom WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have built a custom WCF service which is up and working fine.

I want service show message as metioned in below screen shot

[image: SharePoint custom WCF Error]

though above exception comes my service is up and functional.

Reason why I'm getting above error is I'm trying to upload file along with filename (string) and FileContent(Stream).

```
 public string ActivityAttachment(Stream Uploading, string CommentId, string FileName)
 {
 // My Code to save file on Server
 }
```

But when I deploy the same solution in another machine I'm getting the SharePoint error which is  redirect as mentioned  in below screen shot.

Impact is that it's redirecting to error.aspx page whenever i'm trying to Upload file using xmlHttpRequest

[image]

(ignore sharepoint error message)

Just help how I can get service page rather SharePoint one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the following in Your web.config file:

```
<compilation batch="false" debug="true" /> 
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

Comment: do I need to add this is service web.config or my web application's root config file.
If it's web application's related i can't do so, as I have restrictions to access/ Modify that.